# ETL batch processing

Tags: batch-processing, schedule

I'm looking for some open source technology that will allow me to create scheduled batch processing (e.g. Query every 1 hour some SQL DB like Oracle, and insert to Kafka. It is possible that some transformation will be done to the data between). The thing is that I need to be able to transport large amount of data ("big data" - Oracle queries could return 10GB or more).

I read about Apache Airflow for example, but it does not seem to fit for large amount of data.

What other technologies can I use for that purpose?

Answer (score 0):

One simple and easy solution to this is to use an open-source ETL tool like Talend Open Studio for Big Data to create an ETL that reads your data from oracle and then writes it to Kafka. Considering that's all you need, you can get this done with talend using three components;

- tOracleInput
- tMap
- tKafkaOutput

[Talend - Kafka Documentation](https://help.talend.com/reader/KxVIhxtXBBFymmkkWJ~O4Q/sL0zK_KXztXMoebj8M7~Ug)

Another solution would be to code your ETL in an spark job to write to Kafka directly from your spark code. Spark provides really really fast in-memory processing if you have enough memory so you can leverage that.

Also, since you are to do this in an hourly batch, you should filter your oracle input based on time to only fetch the incremental rows, not the entire snapshot.

Comment: I couldn't find a native way in Talend for scheduling jobs(from what I searched on Google). About Spark  - I'm looking for no-code (or minimal) solution. About the hourly batch, of course I'm using time based quries, and fetch only the new data, but this data can get up to a few GBs.

Comment: @ChikChak, that's right, there's no native scheduling in the open-source version, you have to build your job and call the batch file from a cron job.

Answer (score 0):

You should see all of [Apache Big Data projects](https://projects.apache.org/projects.html?category#big-data) and the [Oracle GoldenGate for BigData](https://www.oracle.com/middleware/data-integration/goldengate/big-data/).
The problem is being solved by the Apache with a solution combination of Big Data tools.

And You could use the [Spring Framework: Spring Batch](https://spring.io/projects/spring-batch) for open source solutions.

Comment: I wouldn't like to use GoldenGate since it's a very specific solution for Oracle only, I said Oracle as an example, it could be any other DB.

Answer (score 0):

Is [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) good enough for your use case?

While it is a general purpose job scheduling library, but I think it could be used for long-running ETL tasks too.

**Quote from official website:**

> Quartz is a [richly featured](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/introduction.html#features), open source job scheduling library that
>   can be integrated within virtually any Java application - from the
>   smallest stand-alone application to the largest e-commerce system.
>   Quartz can be used to create simple or complex schedules for executing
>   tens, hundreds, or even tens-of-thousands of jobs; jobs whose tasks
>   are defined as standard Java components that may execute virtually
>   anything you may program them to do. The Quartz Scheduler includes
>   many enterprise-class features, such as support for JTA transactions
>   and clustering.
>
> Quartz is freely usable, licensed under the [Apache 2.0 license](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0).

Comment: In addition to which technology that will do the actual logic?

Comment: @ChikChak A simple Java program (Scheduler) plus your ETL (Job), like this [example](https://www.baeldung.com/quartz).

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of Apache Airflow is slightly misleading. It is meant to be used for programmatically authoring, scheduling and monitoring workflows.

You can use various techs to do the ETL job you intend to do. Airflow is meant to be orchestrator. It can do

- Monitoring Cron jobs
- Transferring data from one place to other (which might include periodically fetching data from multiple sources)
- Machine Learning Pipelines.

Airflow has integration with all major cloud vendors as well. MS Azure, GCP, AWS. [See this](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/integration.html#service-integrations). It can work well with Qubole, Spark and others.

I would urge you to look at 2 separate things in 2 separate lights. Doing actual ETL job might require it's own setup and running it in a scheduled way is where Airflow comes into picture. Airflow can also help you with the devops aspect of your job.

Comment: I haven't mentioned but I also have already up and running streaming Apache NiFi flows. Do you think it would work well for Airflow to be the scheduler of NiFi flows? I.e., something like Airflow will schedule a trigger to run a query into some MQ that NiFi will consume and thus remain stream, or is it overkill to use Airflow just for that?

Comment: In my head, creating a DAG that contains 2 operators - one for reading from Oracle, and one for writing to Kafka, won't work well, since they'll communicate via the Xcom, which is simply an SQL table, and when the data is about a few GBs, doesn't sound like a good idea. On the other hand, another option is creating an oeprator of Oracle2Kafka, but then I won't be able to do any further transformation between (like splitting the data).